# vba pastespecial error 1004 sometimes only

Tags: excel, vba

Hi i have a vba macro that will copy data from one workbook to another to starting from a specific cell.
The macro has been running with excel 2010 without any problems, but now i am making changes in excel 2016, i am not too sure if this problem is related to the version.

```
IngToRows = 35
objFile.Range("A1").Select
objFile.Range("A5:AP" & IngToRows).copy
objSheet.Range("A4:AP" & IngToRows).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

the error occur at `objSheet.Range("A4:AP" & IngToRows).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`
saying that pastespecial method of range class failed error code 1004, but the weird thing is that it works sometimes but fail the other times. I tried to run it 5 times and maybe 3 out of 5 times error occur, i am not too sure what is really happening, when the error occur, i tried to go to the worksheet directly and ctrl + v, and it works fine, that means it did copied to the clipboard without problem.

I have seen many people talking about it online, but none of the solution helps..

> Edit: I tried to add the line `Application.cutCopyMode=False` before I copy to clear the clipboard but that didn't help

Comment: You could just paste into the topmost, leftmost cell: `objSheet.Range("A4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`. Not sure if it will change the error.

Comment: maybe that the ranges are not the same size? one is `A5:AP35` and the other `A4:AP35`  Try: `objSheet.Range("A4:AP" & IngToRows - 1).Value = objFile.Range("A5:AP" & IngToRows).Value`

Comment: @BigBen I have tried that too, but the error still occur once a while

Comment: @ScottCraner hum, i never thought of that but i can give it a try first. I dun think thats really the issue tho, since it works sometimes

Comment: Have you tried `objSheet.Range("A4:AP" & IngToRows).value = objFile.Range("A5:AP" & IngToRows-1).value` instead of select/copy/paste?

Comment: @VBAPete Thanks for the advance, it did copy the data, but since i need to copy the format as well, i don't think this is gonna work in my case

Comment: @kownowl No worries, I just aasumed because of xlPasteValues. Sid Scott Craners solution solve your issue?

Comment: @VBAPete no that didn't help as well..

Comment: does anyone have a clue,,i realized it usually happens after 2 success run..

Comment: @kownowl The problem is probably somewhere else in your code. Can your share the whole Sub?